# optparse(): Input validation

Tags: python, validation, optparse

My apology in advance if it's already answered somewhere; I've been in the python site since last hr. but didn't quite figure out how I can I do this. My script should take the options like this:

```
myScript.py -f <file-name> -e [/ -d]
myScript.py -s <string> -e [/ -d]
myScript.py -f <file-name> [/ -s <string>] -e -w [<file_name>]
```

i.e. `-f`/`-s`,`-e`/`-d` are mandatory options but `-f`&`-s` cannot be used together and the same as with `-e`&`-d` options - cannot be used together. How can I put the check in place?

Another question, if I may ask at the same time: How can I use `-w` option (when used) with or w/o a value? When no value is supplied, it should take the default value otherwise the supplied one. 
Any help greatly appreciated. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I did anything with optparse, but I took a brief look through the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) and an old program.

"*-f/-s,-e/-d are mandatory options but -f&-s cannot be used together and the same as with -e&-d options - cannot be used together. How can I put the check in place?*"

For mutual exclusivity, you have to do the check yourself, for example:

```
parser.add_option("-e", help="e desc", dest="e_opt", action="store_true")
parser.add_option("-d", help="d desc", dest="d_opt", action="store_true")
(opts, args) = parser.parse_args()
if (parser.has_option("-e") and parser.has_option("-d")):
    print "Error!  Found both d and e options.  You can't do that!"
    sys.exit(1)
```

Since the example options here are boolean, you could replace the if line above with:

```
if (opts.e_opt and opts.d_opt):
```

See the section [How optparse handles errors](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#how-optparse-handles-errors) for more.

"*How can I use -w option (when used) with or w/o a value?*"

I've never figured out a way to have an optparse option for which a value is, well, optional.  AFAIK, you have to set the option up to have values or to not have values.  The closest I've come is to specify a [default value](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#default-values) for an option which must have a value.  Then that entry doesn't have to be specified on the command line.  Sample code :

```
parser.add_option("-w", help="warning", dest="warn", default=0)
```

An aside with a (hopefully helpful) suggestion:

If you saw the docs, you did see the part about how "mandatory options" is an oxymoron, right?     ;-p     Humor aside, you may want to consider re-designing the interface, so that:

- Required information isn't entered using an "option".
- Only one argument (or group of arguments) enters data which could be mutually exclusive.  In other words, instead of "-e" or "-d", have "-e on" or "-e off".  If you want something like "-v" for verbose and "-q" for quiet/verbose off, you can store the values into one variable:

```python
parser.add_option("-v", help="verbose on", dest="verbose", action="store_true")
parser.add_option("-q", help="verbose off", dest="verbose", action="store_false")
```

This particular example is borrowed (with slight expansion) from the section [Handling boolean (flag) options](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#handling-boolean-flag-options).  For something like this you might also want to check out the [Grouping Options](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#grouping-options) section; I've not used this feature, so won't say more about it.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I think you got me close enough to the things I'm actually looking for. I'm gonna try your suggestion shortly and shall let you know how it goes. Cheers!!

Comment: @Matt: Wondering if you can help: if I go like this: `myScript.py -f -e` it's taking _**-e**_ as the value for `-f` option - how can I stop that? Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers:  If -f is to be a flag (i.e. just an on/off option), then see the Handling boolean options section linked to in the answer.  If -f needs to pick up a value from the CLI, then you must give it a value when you call the program.  That value will need to appear right after the -f; e.g. `my_script -f f_value -e`.

Comment: @Matt: Sorry, I wasn't very clear, I see. Yes, `-f` (or `-s`) needs to pick up a value from the CLI and what I mean is: if the value (for _-f_) is not given an "error" should be raised, in stead of taking the next option as "a" value. Sorry for creating the confusion. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers:  AFAIK, you'll have to do your own checking to be sure that the entry after `-f` is really a value for the option.

Answer (score 2):

You should try with `argparse` if you are using 2.7+.
[This section](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) should be what you want.

Tl;dr:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('--bar', action='store_false')
```

makes `--foo` and `--bar` mutually exclusive. See detailed `argparse` usage for more informations on using `ArgumentParser`s

Remember that `optparse` is deprecated, so using `argparse` is a good idea anyway.

Comment: That's a problem for me - can't use v2.7, it's still pretty much non-stranded; no major Linux distro includes v2.7 as default.

Comment: @MacUsers 2.7 IS Python's current version for the 2.x series. Even the 2.x series becomes outdated, what prevents you from requiring Python's main version?

Comment: Well, if you look in the RHEL, CentOs, Ubuntu (Fedora is not something you should count on) for example, all of those still install v2.4 as default with an optional v2.6 installation side by side. Only Ubuntu, includes v2.6 as default. When you are writing some tool-sets for for grid computing, using non-stranded version makes thing totally unusable.

Comment: @MacUsers Isn't Ubuntu's latest under 2.7? Also if you want to use elaborate command line arguments patterns, I'd rather mess with `sys.argv` than use `optparse`.

Comment: @MacUsers: I used F15 and it's stocked with 2.7.1

Comment: @sixfeetsix: Fedora is not for production system, if you know what I mean. Cheers!!

Comment: A well then you'll have to use optparse, which from memory doesn't support mutual exclusion.

Comment: @Evpok: I use python at/for work and the entire sector is RHEL (SL, CentOs, etc.) based. I believe, Ububtu 11 provides the support for v2.7 but AFAIK, v10.04 supplies v2.6 as default.

Comment: [argparse](http://code.google.com/p/argparse/) is also available for older Python versions.

Comment: @Evpok, @sixfeetsix: Yes, I see that it's not supported in v2.6 - there is no work around at all? Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers: Why the snide against Fedora and not Ubuntu?

Comment: @sixfeetsix: Actually, it's the same for Ubuntu as well, I don't know anyone uses Ubuntu for production work either (apart from using as Media Center or Windows users are trying out Linux). It's Debian, what is used instead.

Comment: @omz: Even though the link says it's backported but python docs says "New in version 2.7". Also, when I try `import argparse` I get `ImportError: No module named argparse'.

Comment: Huuh oh well, I won't reply more to that more than to say that my arguing about what each linux distro is better for is behind me ;)

Comment: @MacUsers I do use KUbuntu for production. The university I'm working at is pretty liberal :)

Comment: Just wondering, is there any way to filter out only the supplied options as a list (e.g ['-f', '-e']) or something? It's possible with getopt(). Any idea? Cheers!!

Comment: @Evpok: Here is the catch - Uni maybe but not the project, especially the big international ones. I also have a Ubuntu desktop but as one of the partners of the project I work for (EU and UK), we can only run SL/SLC and CentOS - middleware just doesn't run on any other platform.

Comment: @MacUsers You have to install it of course. It's part of the standard library in 2.7, but you'll have to download it separately for older versions. Try `easy_install argparse`.

Comment: @MacUsers:  While I get what you're saying, the group in which I work (a science lab of about 25 people in a "large (about 10K people) government institution") recently switched from CentOS to Ubuntu for production work.  Also, I believe Wikipedia uses Ubuntu: http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2008/10/wikipedia-adopts-ubuntu-for-its-server-infrastructure.ars

Comment: @GreenMatt: CentOS is kind of dead, (we may never see CentOS-6 at all), so I think a switch is essential and Ubuntu is reasonably good choice, I believe. I'm also in a Science Lab, working for Grid/Atlas project. In UK, Ubuntu is still not "very" popular choice (I think) for production work and definitely not within LHC community. A group of people at Earth Science use Debian for their in house development though. I like Ubuntu; it's lot better "supported" but our middleware only supports SL/SLC (and CentOS).